# How to continue page numbering from the highest page number in the previous section?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

In my Word document i adding new Section:

```
var defaultSection = mainPart.Document.Descendants<SectionProperties>().First();
var paragraph2 = new Paragraph();
var paragraphProperties2 = new ParagraphProperties();

var sectionProperties2 = defaultSection.Clone() as SectionProperties;

var sectionTypeCur = sectionProperties2.Descendants<SectionType>().FirstOrDefault();
sectionProperties2.RemoveChild(sectionTypeCur);
var sectionType2 = new SectionType() { Val = SectionMarkValues.NextPage };

 var pageNumberType2 = new PageNumberType()
     {
       ChapterSeparator = defaultPageNumbering.ChapterSeparator,
       ChapterStyle = defaultPageNumbering.ChapterStyle,
       Format = defaultPageNumbering.Format,
       Start = null
      };

  var pageNumberTypeCur = sectionProperties2.Descendants<PageNumberType>().FirstOrDefault();
  sectionProperties2.RemoveChild(pageNumberTypeCur);
  sectionProperties2.Append(pageNumberType2);

  var titlePageCur2 = sectionProperties2.Descendants<TitlePage>().FirstOrDefault();
  sectionProperties2.RemoveChild(titlePageCur2);

  paragraphProperties2.Append(sectionProperties2);
  paragraph2.Append(paragraphProperties2);
  lastElementInFirstSection.InsertAfterSelf(paragraph2);
```

And see that in new section page numbering starts from default value. But i want to page numbering continious from the highest page number in the previous section.
How can i do it?

Comment: As the approved answer says but you also need to add the new PageNumberType to the section properties. Currently it is not being added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `SectionMarkValues.Continuous` instead of  `Val = SectionMarkValues.NextPage`. Continuous doesn't go to the next page, so you need to put in a plain next page break too, probably.